# Grails: out vs return

Tags: grails

An strange problem occourse on grails 1.2.4 on my machine only....

We are using an custom taglib which can be accessed from services via gspTagLibraryLookup-bean from AppContext.

On my local machine

```
    <my:span value="abc" title="${my.write(text:'123')}"/>
```

writes:

```
    123<span title="">abc</span> <!-- what i see -->
    <span title="123">abc</span> <!-- what my collegue see -->
```

*my:write* is defied as:

```
    def write = {out << attrs.text}
```

But: If i use return instead of out, the html generate what my collegue see.

Anyone know the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument value for the `title` attribute is evaluated before passing it to `<my:span>`. So if you define `write` as `{out << attrs.text}`, and use it in `<my:span>`, the `write` function will write to `out` before `span` function does, and return nothing - so `123` will be written to output before `<span>`, and the title attribute will be empty.

If you define `write` as `{return attrs.text}`, its evaluation won't write anything to out, and return `123` which will be inserted as value of `title` attribute.

Not sure why the first definition works on your collegue's machine.

Comment: That what i thought ... but live, test, and 3 collegues use *out <<* without problems..... (may an configuratoin problem...)